# How do you use the generative art node in sverchok

Tags: scripting, node-editor, sverchok

I tried to use the generative art node but didn't understand how it works. I looked up the documentation, but I didn't understand anything from it. Can someone help by making the simplest code and break down each section into what it does, so that I get the hung of it?

Comment: what about posting an example what you mean? generative are is a very common term....at least a link to an animation what you want to produce. and "normally" this is a question about a tutorial....but this site is for special problems where you are stuck at...not a site to explain all nodes of sverchok....i would search for sverchok beginner tutorials on yt ...that's my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

"Can someone help by making the simplest code and break down each section into what it does, so that I get the hang of it?" The documentation is basically doing that. The node is used for making recursive shapes. If you don't understand what recursive shapes are google it. There are plenty of good explanations about what they are. This is a beginner friendly explanation by the coding train: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jjeOYMjmDU
The node uses xml syntax to achieve this goal of recursive shapes. The documentation explains what is the syntax to transform (move, rotate, scale) the data input into the generative art node. Copy the tree code and setup your blend file as it is setup in the image below then start tweaking values in the xml script as well as the sverchok nodes and see what happens. Tweaking and breaking things is also a way of learning. If you change values in the xml script in blender's text block editor and then want to see how those values influence the generated shape, then you have to click the re-update all nodes button in the sverchok right-panel active tree properties. Hope this helps.[image: sverchok-gen-art-node-setup]